# Express used to print simple message

Tags: node.js, express

**Express program ::**

```
var express = require('express')
  , async = require('async')
  , http = require('http')
  , mysql = require('mysql');

var app = express();

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: "root",
    database: 'restaurants'
});

connection.connect();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 7004);


app.get('/restaurant/:Key',function(request,response,next){

    var keyName=request.query.Key;
    response.end("Hello, " + keyName + ".");

} );


app.get('/',function(request,response,next){

    response.end("Hello");

} );

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

**Output Test**

I have used a simulation test from POSTMAN browser extension of chrome to simulate get request , I have posted the output in the image below, How can i resolve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've configured your get handler to include Key in the path itself.

If you remove `:Key` it should work as you are expecting:

```
app.get('/restaurant/',function(request,response,next){  
    var keyName=request.query.Key;
    response.end("Hello, " + keyName + ".");
} );
```

Comment: Your information helped.... i extended your solution .... please look at this link (http://stackoverflow.com/q/18525144/2582071) give your feed back please !