# Express to generate JSON

Tags: node.js, express

**I am trying to pass a key value and generate a JSON response based on the key passed**

**Express Program**

```
var express = require('express'),
    async = require('async'),
    http = require('http'),
    mysql = require('mysql');

var app = express();

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: "root",
    database: 'restaurants'
});

connection.connect();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 7004);

app.get('/RestaurantDesc/', function (request, response, next) {

    var keyName = request.query.Key;
    var name_of_restaurants, RestaurantTimings;
    async.series([
        // Get the first table contents
        function (callback) {
            connection.query('SELECT * FROM ', keyName, function (err, rows, fields) {
                console.log('Connection result error ' + err);
                name_of_restaurants = rows;
                callback();
            });
        },
        // Get the second table contents
        function (callback) {
            connection.query('SELECT * FROM RestaurantTimings', function (err, rows, fields)

            {
                console.log('Connection result error ' + err);
                RestaurantTimings = rows;
                callback();
            });
        }
    // Send the response
    ], function (error, results) {
        response.json({
            'restaurants': name_of_restaurants,
                'RestaurantTimings': RestaurantTimings
        });
    });
});

app.get('/RestaurantDesc/', function (request, response, next) {

    var keyName = request.query.Key;
    var name_of_restaurants, RestaurantTimings;
    async.series([
    // Get the first table contents
    function (callback) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM ', keyName, function (err, rows, fields) {
            console.log('Connection result error ' + err);
            name_of_restaurants = rows;
            callback();
        });
    },
    // Get the second table contents
    function (callback) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM RestaurantTimings', function (err, rows, fields)

        {
            console.log('Connection result error ' + err);
            RestaurantTimings = rows;
            callback();
        });
    }

    // Send the response
    ], function (error, results) {
        response.json({
            'restaurants': name_of_restaurants,
                'RestaurantTimings': RestaurantTimings
        });
    });
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

**Test Run::**

**I am getting the JSON response for RestaurantTimings but not the first one where keyvalue is passed , how to resolve this ?**

[image]

Comment: Assuming you are using [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) take a look at: [Escaping query values](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#escaping-query-values)

Comment: That helps ! .... but if you cold edit the query part in my code as the answers .... that practical understanding will help me lot... I am a newbie to this stuff !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two handlers for the path `/RestaurantDesc/` - only one should be kept.

In your query, the syntax is wrong.

Assuming you have a table that looks like this (change these names to match your schema):

```
Table Name: Restaurant
    column:       name
```

And you are using [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql), Change your query to something like this:

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM Restaurant where name = ?', [keyName], function (err, rows, fields) {
    console.log('Connection result error ' + err);
    name_of_restaurants = rows;
    callback();
});
```

The ? is a place holder for values passed in the array of values passed in the second parameter to `query`.

See: [Escaping query values](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#escaping-query-values) for more information on how this works.  Short answer though is that the values will be escaped properly using this approach.

Comment: Thanks ! ... This was exactly what i was looking for !..... and also i need to rethink about my Database design ... Initially i was wrong ! ... I learnt a lot from your answer

Answer (score 0):

The path that does what you want is `/`, not `/RestaurantDesc/`. Look at the first parameter to `app.get()`.

Here's what I get with `http://54.218.73.244:7004/`

```
{
  "restaurants": [
    {
      "restaurantID": 1,
      "restaurantNAME": "CopperChimney",
      "url": "http://54.218.73.244:7002/CopperChimney"
    },
    {
      "restaurantID": 2,
      "restaurantNAME": "Aroy",
      "url": "http://54.218.73.244:7002/Aroy"
    },
    {
      "restaurantID": 3,
      "restaurantNAME": "MarkBoulevard",
      "url": "http://54.218.73.244:7002/MarkBoulevard"
    },
    {
      "restaurantID": 4,
      "restaurantNAME": "Indian",
      "url": "http://54.218.73.244:7002/Indian"
    }
  ],
  "RestaurantTimings": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "RestaurantTime": "8pm to 11pm"
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "RestaurantTime": "10pm to 12pm"
    },
    {
      "_id": 3,
      "RestaurantTime": "11pm to 9pm"
    },
    {
      "_id": 4,
      "RestaurantTime": "10pm to 5pm"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: i am refering to app.get('/RestaurantDesc/' ..... please echeck the test scenario in the pitchire i posted.... passing keyname to query is where i am stuck

Comment: It *works* for you in '/', no? Just use whatever is in there. Or I am not getting your problem maybe?

Comment: not in '/' . In '/' it works as you told ... I am refering to '/RestaurantDesc/'  where i am passing keyvalue to sql query .... Im a newbie to this programming

Comment: Well it seems like there are at least 2 issues here: (1), like @sza said before, you have 2 `/RestaurantDesc/` handlers. Keep just one. (2) You SQL query is wrong. It seems like you are selecting from the TABLE passed by `Key`, where you should in fact have it in your `WHERE` clauses (`restaurant_name=<key>`). Finally, you should really take care to escape inputs to SQL.

Comment: Thanks for this i/p ... can you edit your answer with my code(w.r.t) your solution ... it will hep !

Comment: @Iplay - if you could post your table schema it would help with the solution.

Comment: @dc5 ...... I am selecting all the values from the table ....In one of the answers Nitzan Shaked .... i am trying to get that ..... any Ieas on how to put that in code ... thanks !

Answer (score 0):

try to refer the following links may help

http://book.mixu.net/ch10.html

http://expressjs.com/api.html

Comment: Any links for express that deals with sql queries ?

Comment: by postgresql http://dailyjs.com/2011/09/26/heroku/                 by mysql  https://gist.github.com/clarle/3180770